# Exporting from dicts list to excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Beginner here, I wrote a code where I'd like to export each and every dict inside a list to excel. For now it exports only the last one - name:evan, age:25. I have no idea why. Terminal shows all data but when I try to export it shows the last one. I'd like 'name' and 'age' to be column headers and the corresponding data below

```py
import pandas as pd

people = [
{
    'name':'corey', 
    'age':12,
},
{
    'name':'matt', 
    'age':15,
},
{
    'name':'evan', 
    'age':25
}]


for person in range(len(people)):
    print(people[person]['name'], people[person]['age'])


excel_dict = {}
for s in range(len(people)):
    excel_dict['p_name'] = (people[s]['name'])
    excel_dict['p_age'] = (people[s]['age'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=excel_dict, index=[0])
    df = (df.T)
    print (df)
    df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Comment: What do you think that `df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')` is doing when it is **inside** the loop?

Comment: No difference when I got it after the loop. Same results.

Comment: Of course. You keep overwriting the same file

Comment: whats the point of these rude replies? I'm just a beginner man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
import pandas as pd

people = [
{
    'name':'corey', 
    'age':12,
},
{
    'name':'matt', 
    'age':15,
},
{
    'name':'evan', 
    'age':25
}]


for person in people:
    print(person['name'], person['age'])

df = pd.DataFrame(people)
print(df)
df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
corey 12
matt 15
evan 25

    name  age
0  corey   12
1   matt   15
2   evan   25
```

Comment: unfortunately your code creates 3 separate xlsx files, each containing 1 dict, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: @MichalK sorry I misunderstood your question, I will edit my solution now, thx for the feedback.

Comment: one more thing if you could help. I want to export only 1 column to excel file e.g. name instead of name and age.

Comment: @MichalK If you're dealing with the same list you can simple drop the 'age' column: 
`df.drop('age',axis=1,inplace=True)`